# Batch file not executing for testng suite with database queries

Tags: java, xml, batch-file, testng

I am trying to execute a batch file with testng suite and a XML file linked to a java class.

If I try to execute the batch file I get a failure with no indication of what failed. `cmd.exe` is not showing any exceptions or any reason for why the batch file has failed, only that 1 failure has occurred.

If I run the XML file from Eclipse as testng suite, it is runs without any issue.

```bash
cd <Filepath>
set ProjectPath=<Filepath>
echo %ProjectPath%
set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\lib\*
echo %classpath%
java -cp "%classpath%" org.testng.TestNG FHA_BS_testng.xml
pause
```

Please note, if I run other XML files without database queries, they are running fine from a batch file, (I am just changing the XML file name from the above script). The issue only occurs for database query related XML files.

Below is the java class which needs to be executed by batch file through XML

```java
package other_utilities;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.Data.ExcelDataConfig;
import com.garage.mailLibrary.MailLibrary;

public class FHA_BlazeSupportEmail {
    static java.sql.Connection conn = null;
    static ResultSet result = null;
    static ExcelDataConfig excel;

    @Test
    public  void main() throws Exception {
        excel =new ExcelDataConfig("<Filepath>bug_tracker_mail.xlsx");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + "XXXXXXXXXX" + ":1433;databaseName=" + "BlazeSupport";
        String username = "XXXXX";
        String password = "XXXXX";

        // Initialize Sqldriver instance
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        // Creating the connection providing URL and username password
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        // Checking for the connection( returns boolean false if connected)
        System.out.println(conn.isClosed());

        // For Print
        System.out.println("Data values getting displayed below");
        String sql= "SELECT TKT.Id, TKT.PlatformId, TKT.BugTrackerId, TKT.ExpectedDate, TKT.TimeStampUtc, TKTMD.FirstName, TKTMD.LastName, TKTMD.UserName,     \r\n"
                  + "TKTMD.Email, TKTMD.Title, TKTMD.Details, TKTMD.UserType, ISNULL(TKTMD.TestingOutcomeId, 0) as TestingOutcome\r\n"
                  + "FROM [dbo].[Ticket] TKT    \r\n"
                  + "LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Platform] PF     ON PF.Id = TKT.PlatformId    \r\n"
                  + "LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TicketMetadata] TKTMD     ON TKTMD.TicketId = TKT.Id  \r\n"
                  + "where --CAST(TKT.TimeStampUtc as date) = CAST((GETDATE()) as date)  and \r\n"
                  + "pf.Id = 34";

        PreparedStatement pst2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        result = pst2.executeQuery();

        for(int i=1;i<=getRowCount();i++){
            excel.setdata(0, i, 0, "");
            excel.setdata(0, i, 1, "");
            excel.setdata(0, i, 2, "");
            excel.setdata(0, i, 3, "");
            excel.setdata(0, i, 4, "");
        }

        int counter=0;
        int arrayCount=0;
        int rowCount=1;

        while(result.next()){
            excel.setdata(0, rowCount, 0, result.getString("BugTrackerId"));
            excel.setdata(0, rowCount, 1, result.getString("FirstName"));
            excel.setdata(0, rowCount, 2, result.getString("LastName"));
            excel.setdata(0, rowCount, 3, result.getString("Title"));
            excel.setdata(0, rowCount, 4, result.getString("Email"));
            rowCount++;
        }

        String checkedID[] = new String[getRowCount()];
        MailLibrary mail = new MailLibrary();
        mail.setUsernameAndPassword("xxxxx", "xxxx!!");

        for (int i=1;i<=getRowCount();i++) {
            mail.setSMTP("xxxx");
            mail.fromMailId("xxxxxx");
            mail.setSubject("You have BlazeSupport Ticket Updates");
            String userID = excel.getdata(0, i, 4);
            String FName = excel.getdata(0, i, 1);
            String LName = excel.getdata(0, i, 2);
            String email="";

            try {
                email = excel.getdata(0,i,4);
                if(email.isEmpty()){
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                continue;
            }

            //we are adding descriptions from excel in the form of list for that creating a html tag and below list is added dynamically
            String description="<ul>";

            //there will be multiple entries for same userID so the userID is already checked then we need to continue
            if(i>1){
                String isThisRepeatedID = "No";

                for(String s:checkedID) {
                    if(userID.equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                        isThisRepeatedID="Yes";
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(isThisRepeatedID.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                    continue;
                }
            }

            for (int j=1;j<=getRowCount();j++){
                String newUserID = excel.getdata(0, j, 4);
                if(userID.equalsIgnoreCase(newUserID)){
                    String desc =excel.getdata(0, j, 3);
                    String BTID =excel.getdata(0, j, 0);
                    description = description+"<li>"+BTID+" - "+desc+"</li>";
                }
            }

            //moving used ID to array   
            checkedID[arrayCount]=userID;
            arrayCount++;
            mail.ToMailId(XXXX);

            String createTable ="<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n" + 
                                "<html>\r\n" + 
                                "<style>\r\n" + 
                                "table, th, td {\r\n" + 
                                "  border:1px solid black;\r\n" + 
                                " \r\n" + 
                                "}\r\n" + 
                                "</style>\r\n" + 
                                "<body>\r\n" + 
                                "\r\n" + 
                                "<p>Hi "+FName+" "+LName+"</p>"+
                                "<p> </p>"+
                                "<p>There have been updates made to ticket(s) you submitted in BlazeSupport in your bridge environment.</p>"+
                                "<p>Please log into the following URL to navigate to blazesupport and review the updates.</p>"+
                                "<p></p>"+
                                "<h2 align=\"center\"></h2>\r\n" + 
                                "\r\n" ;

            String note="<p></p>"+
                        "<p>https://fhabridgetest.bridgelive.net/</p>";

            String html = createTable+description+"</ul>"+note;
            mail.setHtmlMessage(html.toString());
            mail.sendMail();

            // break;
        }
    }

    public static int getRowCount(){
        int rowCount=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=excel.rowcount(0);i++){
            if(!excel.getdata(0, i, 0).isEmpty()){
                rowCount++;
            }
        }
        return rowCount;
    }

}
```

If I run the above java class in eclipse through XML suite, it will execute.
But if i create a batch file for this and run, it is not executing

Comment: hi & welcome! ..sounds like the "diff" of (working and non working) xml files is significant. please share([edit]) ..or find it:)

Comment: Check the log files of the database for any errors.

Comment: Thank you xerx593, there is not difference between the running and not running xml file except for the class name.

Comment: There is no issue with db, issue is with batch file or xml. not sure jdweng